# Update .xlsx file

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using **PHPExcel_1.8.0.**
I have many input files and I want to read each file and to save them **run time** into a single output file.
I have tried but the output file is overwriting for each file.
Let me explain in brief:
I have 5 files having records of 5 different employees and I want to put these records in a single file through php. I have set a loop, so the output file is saving only the last employee record due to overwriting.
I want something like append in php.
**Here is my code:**

```
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
define('EOL', (PHP_SAPI == 'cli') ? PHP_EOL : '<br />');
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
require_once 'index.php';

require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
$dirlist = dirToArray('input');
foreach ($dirlist AS $value) {
    $info = new SplFileInfo($value);
    $vFileExtension = $info->getExtension();
    if ($vFileExtension == 'xlsx' || $vFileExtension == 'xls') {
        $inputFileName = "input/".$value;
        $objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5();
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
        $sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true, true);
        $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
        $i = 1;
        foreach ($sheetData AS $key => $row) {
            foreach ($row AS $index => $rec) {
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($index . $i, $newtext);
            }
            $i++;
        }
        $objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_HeaderFooterDrawing();
        $objDrawing->setName('PHPExcel logo');
        $objDrawing->setPath('./images/phpexcel_logo.gif');
        $objDrawing->setHeight(36);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHeaderFooter()->addImage($objDrawing, PHPExcel_Worksheet_HeaderFooter::IMAGE_HEADER_LEFT);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setOrientation(PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup::ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setPaperSize(PHPExcel_Worksheet_PageSetup::PAPERSIZE_A4);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Data');
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
        $callStartTime = microtime(true);
        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
        $objWriter->save("output/result.xlsx");
        $callEndTime = microtime(true);
        $callTime = $callEndTime - $callStartTime;
        $callStartTime = microtime(true);
        echo $value . ' has been generated!' . EOL;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Problem #1. Stop relying on the extension, and let PHPExcel's IOFactory load() method identify the actual format of the uploaded file

Comment: Problem #2. You don't use PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5() if the file really is an OfficeOpenXML format .xlsx file, you use PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007() - the IOFactory load() will deal with this for you

Comment: Problem #3. If you want to merge all 5 into a new spreadsheet file, then instantiate your new PHPExcel object ___before___ the loop, and save it ___after___ the loop

Comment: Thank you Mark for your cooperation. 
#1 I have only .xlsx files
#2 I have included that file IOFactory but it didn't work
#3 I have tried the last one right now but unfortunately this one also didn't work

Comment: #1 - If you have only `.xlsx` files, why bother allowing `.xls` as well.... and it's still safer to let PHPExcel identify the file itself... if your files are genuine `.xlsx` files, then the `PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5` reader should throw an exception.... using `IOFactory::load()` eliminates this because PHPExcel will select the correct Reader by testing the files rather than by making assumptions

Comment: #2 - explain what you mean by "didn't work"

Comment: #3 - If you have made those changes, edit the question and show your current code